# How could multiple amcharts be exported to PDF file?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have N AmCharts that I have to be exported to the one PDF file.
Could you please share any example how to achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JavaScript can't make PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

Take look at this tutorial for export to pdf :

http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/exporting-charts-and-maps-as-an-image-or-pdf/

Comment: I took at the tutorial. No example for multiple charts.

Comment: I could use chart.AmExport.output for export, but how can I combine the several charts to one PDF?\

Comment: AmCharts V4: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/generating-multi-content-pdf-export/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example for multiple charts export

http://www.amcharts.com/tips/exporting-multiple-charts-on-the-page-to-a-single-pdf/

Comment: Can you post some content from the link?

Comment: This link have updated tutorial on how to export charts into a pdf or image: http://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/exporting-charts-and-maps-to-images-or-pdf/